# jquery replace each input with it's value. then switch/toggle back to having inputs

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, dom-manipulation

I have a table created by an AJAX request.  Each of the TDs have a Textbox Input inside it.  This allows the user to edit content.  I want to have a "read only" mode where the user can't edit content (at the user's discretion).  For this, I want the user to be able to press a button (radio buttons would also be fine) that replaces each of the Textbox Inputs with a

tag containing the value of the text box as its text.  Currently, my code replaces each of Inputs with the text "object Object".  (Maybe I haven't converted the values to text strings correctly??)  Any tips to let me know what's going wrong would be greatly appreaciated.  Thanks!!

This is my current script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#permissionsbutton").live('click',function(){
        sss = $('.cells').each(function(){$(this).val()});
        $(".cells").replaceWith("<p class='readonlycells' type='text'>" + sss + "</p>");
    });
    // if this worked, I would write another few lines
    // to be able to switch back to having inputs
</script>
```

And this is a snippet of what the HTML could look like:

```
<div id="readwrite" class="settings">
    <h3>Permissions</h3>
    <button id="permissionsbutton">Switch to Read Only Mode</button>
</div>
<table><tr>
    <td><input class='cells' type=text value='Steve'></td>
    <td><input class='cells' type=text value='Mary'></td>
    <td><input class='cells' type=text value='Big Bird'></td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: Is "cells" the class of the textarea or the td?  It looks like you're looping over the tds and not getting down into the textareas.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's `each` function returns the jQuery object it was called on (`$('cells')` in your case). So your current code is replacing each element matched by the `.cells` selector with the jQuery object, which is serializing to "object Object".

What you want is something more like

```
$("#permissionsbutton").live('click', function() {
    $(".cells").each(function() {
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#permissionsbutton").live('click',function(){ 
  $('.cells').each(function(){
    var cell=$(this);
    cell.replaceWith('<span class="cells_ro">'+cell.val()+'</span>');
  }); 
});
```

Or just disable cells:

```
$("#permissionsbutton").live('click',function(){ 
  $('.cells').attr('disabled',true);
});
```

Comment: I agree with you, but I don't think this script requires .each().  You could just do $('.cells').attr('disabled',true).  Just FYI. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$("#permissionsbutton").click(function(){
$('.cells').attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

[Try it here](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/L4xTh/)